# Conversion shortarray to bytearray & bytearray to shortarray

Tags: java, android, arrays, short

I have tried [this **short2byte and byte2short** conversion, works fine but time consuming.](http://short2byteandbytetoshort.blogspot.in/)

I am converting **byte to short** as shown below

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(bData).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(sData);
```

In same fashion I want to convert back **short to byte.**

I have searched and seen many examples but did not get it as I want.

Comment: I don't think you could get the conversion any faster than that.

Comment: That conversion looks at every short only once, and does a very efficient bitwise operation on it.

Comment: @Cruncher what you say about using ByteBuffer?? I think it taking less time then that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the way.

**conversion byte to short using ByteBuffer**

```
byte[] bData= {};
short[] sData= new short[bData.length/2];
// to turn bytes to shorts as either big endian or little endian. 
ByteBuffer.wrap(bData).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(sData);
```

**conversion short to byte using ByteBuffer**

```
// to turn shorts back to bytes.
byte[] bData= new byte[sData.length * 2];
ByteBuffer.wrap(bData).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().put(sData);
```